# pattern for keeping data produced by many instances of a class

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

My Python program has a main.py module which creates many board objects from the Board class. The Board class uses the Brain class to decide what can happen on the board. The Brain class uses the Data class to help it make decisions.

The problem I'm having is the every time any Board object has the Brain do something, new information has to be added to the *same* Python dictionary in the Data class. I'm afraid to say it, but I really do think the spirit of this dictionary in the Data class is that it needs to be "global". What is the correct pattern so all instances can write to the *same* dictionary? Should I even be using a Data class to hold the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a separate class to hold the dictionary then you can create it like this:

```
class Data:
    info = {}
    def __init__(self):
        ...
```

and then you can have whatever other code you want inside the data class after this. To read what is in `info` you can either call `Data.info` or when you have an instance of the Data class you can use `my_instance.info` but no matter what the instance is it will always read the same info dictionary. Hope this answers your question

Comment: I agree that your solution works. Thanks!! I have also been considering using the Singleton pattern. I know that would only allow one copy of the class to be made. With your class many copies can be made but they all happen be objects that point to the same info dictionary. I'm super interested to learn when you would use one over the other. I'm sort of new to trying to use special patterns like this.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider using DI to maintain the number of dictionary instances instead of making it singleton. If you make it singleton you can't have dictionary per user for example.